# Caffe error while testing: Check failed: count_ == proto.data_size() (9408 vs. 0)

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

I have trained a googlenet on Caffe and now I want to do testing, so I use a deploy.prototxt and the pretrained weights and assign them to Net. But I receive this error (interestingly after a message that says network is initialized)

```
I0927 17:51:41.171922  5336 net.cpp:255] Network initialization done.
I0927 17:51:41.195708  5336 net.cpp:744] Ignoring source layer label_imgdata_1_split
F0927 17:51:41.195746  5336 blob.cpp:496] Check failed: count_ == proto.data_size() (9408 vs. 0)
```

Apparently I can't copy paste the whole prototxts because of the character limit here. I am adding what it looks like without the body which is more or less the same (except phase: TRAIN and phase:TEST parts ofc). The body is identical to the example here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet

One note: I read in hdf5 data during training, and I just use a python script during test (I perform the same preprocessing that I do while creating hdf5 data / so I don't use caffe's io.transform and I don't subtract the mean at all (works better this way)) -though the error is during the initialization and not read in data part

What my deploy looks like:

```
name: "GoogleNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 10 dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 } }
}

.....

  layer {
  name: "loss3/classifier"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5/7x7_s1"
  top: "loss3/classifier"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 7
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  top: "prob"
}
```

And here is how my train prototxt looks like:

```
name: "GoogleNet"

layer {
  name: "imgdata"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "label"
   hdf5_data_param {
      source: "/media/DATA/DetDataWOMeanSubt/train_h5_list.txt"
      batch_size: 64
      shuffle: true
      }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }

}

layer {
  name: "imgdata"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "imgdata"
  top: "label"
   hdf5_data_param {
      source: "/media/DATA/DetDataWOMeanSubt/eval_h5_list.txt"
      batch_size: 128
      shuffle: true
      }
 include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}

....

layer {
  name: "loss3/classifier"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5/7x7_s1"
  top: "loss3/classifier"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 7
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_weight: 1
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy/top-1"
  type: "Accuracy"
  include { phase: TEST }
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy/top-1"
  accuracy_param { top_k: 1 }
}
```

And here is how I initiliaze the network:

```
net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights,  # contains the trained weights
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)
```

And I do get this warning before the Net is initialized ( it seems to continue initializing the network anyway)

```
DEPRECATION WARNING - deprecated use of Python interface
W0927 17:51:40.486548  5336 _caffe.cpp:140] Use this instead (with the named "weights" parameter):
W0927 17:51:40.486551  5336 _caffe.cpp:142] Net('/home/x/Desktop/caffe-caffe-0.16/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt', 1, weights='/home/x/Desktop/caffe-caffe-0.16/models/bvlc_googlenet/logs_iter_60000.caffemodel')
```

(But when I do as suggested it doesn't work)

I have done testing many times before using Caffe, I don't know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has been wondering, it turns out I have trained the model with a different version of caffe and was trying to test with another. I have two versions installed on my computer and it seems I was simply importing the older one during testing with python script (for training I had directly referenced and used the caffe tools under build) that is defined in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The difference between versions is not too dramatic, but it seems there was a mismatch while reading prototoxt.